# How I do make a javascript or jquery counter that counts up infinitely from a number daily

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to make a javascript or jquery counter that counts up but the starting number needs to be controlled by the client through WordPress and the increment needs to be controlled by the client also. The way it should work is that the start number (ex. 5,000,000) should keep counting up starting at  5,000,000 and not 0, then every 24 hours it should increase by 1,500,000. I have the following code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

           var base = <?php echo the_field('number_displayed', 'option'); ?>;
           var rate = <?php echo the_field('number_increment', 'option'); ?> / 86400 / 1000;

        setInterval(function() {
           var count = Math.floor(rate + base).toLocaleString('en');
           $('.count').text(count);

        }

   });
```

Please help

Comment: Do your page every refreshes ? How do you keep the page alive from not expiring ?

Comment: You'll probably have to write a cron job to make a script run automatically.  Since the javascript is client side, if you want it to work in javascript, you will have to keep the page open (and only for that client)

Comment: @DinoMyte It should count after every refresh

Comment: @ntgCleaner a cron job?

Comment: @MikeL5799, as ntgCleaner mentioned thats not something you would like to do in javascript since it won't retain any previous state. You would need external job which kicks off in every 24 hour and based on the criteria and previously calculated value displays the new value.

Comment: So I can't have the counter just run and just increase by 1,500,000 every 24 hours? @DinoMyte

Comment: You can. The only issue is that if you page refreshes, the clock would reset and would start from the beginning.

Comment: starting from the beginning is fine if the page refreshes @DinoMyte

Comment: @DinoMyte  ok I got the calculations working any idea on how to animate that?

Comment: Try using jquery animation as per your requirement. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: @DinoMyte for some reason jquery animate doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I would store the initial value of the counter (5,000,000), the increment rate converted to seconds (1,500,000 per day divided by (24*60*60)), and the Universal Time that this counter is initialized/set-in motion.

Then, to display the counter, the value you want is: (( now() - stored_utc) * rate_in_seconds) + initial_counter.

And use that to seed your setInterval timer.

Sorry about not providing code, I haven't touched Wordpress or PHP in a long time.

Comment: Note that the initial calculation must be all done server side, or you may get variation depending upon the time zone of the visitor.
And make sure that now() is rounded to seconds.